# How to join two tables in sql so that all values of one attribute are present, regardless whether from first or second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I will try my best to explain this. Let's say I have a table like this

| Name | Year | Present_category | Present_count | Mother |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 2023 | sweets | 3 | Linda |
| Mary | 2022 | sweets | 2 | Linda |
| Linda | 2022 | sweets | 4 |  |
| Linda | 2021 | sweets | 1 |  |
| Linda | 2021 | clothes | 2 |  |

And I want to transform it like this: (aggregate by present_category and year and have present count for own and mother in the same row)
Linda does not have a mother.

| Name | Year | Present_category | Present_count_own | Mother | Present_count_mother |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 2023 | sweets | 3 | Linda |  |
| Mary | 2022 | sweets | 2 | Linda | 4 |
| Mary | 2021 | sweets |  | Linda | 1 |
| Mary | 2021 | clothes |  | Linda | 2 |
| Linda | 2022 | sweets | 4 |  |  |
| Linda | 2021 | sweets | 1 |  |  |
| Linda | 2021 | clothes | 2 |  |  |

Escpecially important to me are rows 3 and 4 in the result table: Mary did not have this combination of category and year, but still the rows are there, because these combos are present for the mother (Linda).
Put it another way: For every name I need all combinatiosn of year / category that exist for its own name and for the mother.

Is this possible? I couldn't find a way. Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Please tell us your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).  Also, research "full outer join".

Comment: This will be much harder in MySQL, which doesn't have FULL JOIN, so we really do need to know what kind of database you're using.

Comment: Sorry! It's PostgreSQL @TimBiegeleisen. Unfortunately, full outer join didn't do the trick for me :-/

Comment: Should have said: It's PostgreSQL @JoelCoehoorn But unfortunately, I could not make it work with full outer join. The rows 3 and 4 would not appear :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need CROSS JOIN. Try to look it up and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into using a self referential table call.  I worked out the solution on Oracle but I checked that Postgresql supports self-referential call[OpenRocket](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/self-join-in-postgresql-538#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20perform%20a%20self-join%2C%20you%20have,comparison%20and%20eliminate%20the%20condition%20of%20same%20rows.).  The concept is that in a single table there is a relationship between the name and mother fields since the mothers' name has to be in the name field as well.  A self-referential join occurs when the table is related to itself by using an alias and join the mother field with the name field. It is a common structure that you find in organization personnel charts.  A supervisor is also an employee.  So, you can lookup the employee supervisor information by joining a supervisor to the employee ID in the same table.

Since you are only using a single value  you can use a correlated scalar subquery.  The output of the field, **Present_count_mother** is generated by a select statement joined to the **own** table.

If you have self-referring fields and multiple fields to return, you can use a left outer join. In the example below the loj table alias is joined to provide the **Persent_count_mother_loj** field.

Good luck!

If the original table is "a" then:

```
Select
own.name,own.year,own.present_category, own.Present_count Present_count_own,own.Mother,
(Select Present_count FROM a  where a.name = own.mother and a.year = own.year and a.present_category = own.present_category) Present_count_mother,
loj.Present_count Persent_count_mother_loj
from
a own 
left join
a loj
ON
 loj.name = own.mother and loj.year = own.year and loj.present_category = own.present_category

order by own.year desc, own.name Desc, own.present_category desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this early next week and let you know how it goes!

Comment: As it's currently written, the code is not visibly separated from the text description. Please enclose your code within 3 "`", i.e.

``` This is a code block ```